# Variable IDs in C#

Tags: c#, windows

When programming a Windows Forms application I found myself having to create a variable amount of text fields according to the number of inputs.

I decided to name these `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, ..., `nameN`.

Now I want to be able to save the user's input to a text file. To do this I need to get the text from the text boxes into separate variables to be able to write this to the text file.

This would result in a for loop like this:

```
for(i=0; i < totalnames; i++)
{
    string varname= "name" + i;
}
```

But this way I cannot get the value from the text boxes. How can I get the separate values from the text boxes to write them to the text file?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you want to load them back up as well into the correct Textboxes?

Comment: Looks like homework to me...

Comment: this.Controls[varname].Text, probably.

Comment: It's not homework.. Just a project I'm working on for myself.

No I just want to save them to a file, when it gets reloaded it draws from that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the form controls, keep references to them in a list:

```
// probably at the class level...
List<TextBox> myTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

// then when you create them...
myTextBoxes.Add(name1);
// etc.
```

Then later, when you need to reference them, use the list:

```
foreach (var textBox in myTextBoxes)
{
    // get the value from the text box and use it in your output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a List of string List and add your name in it. Then use StreamWriter to add the name in your file:

```
        List<string> myListOfNames = new List<string>();
        int totalnames = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalnames; i++)
        {
            myListOfNames.Add("name" + i);
        }


        using (StreamWriter writer =  new StreamWriter("C:\\MyTextFile.txt", true))
        {
            foreach (string name in myListOfNames)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(name);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two pennies worth, because the OP originally said **Windows Form Application** - I would have a **Save** `button`, which when fired, the code behind will grab all the Textboxes and save to the file. You can add your own filtering for textboxes yourself if you want.

Firstly here is the code behind for the button event:

```
    private void saveToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\k\\saveToFile.txt", true))
        {
            if (this.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                var textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
                foreach (TextBox textbox in textBoxes)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(textbox.Name + "=" + textbox.Text);
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

A simple forn to prove the point, each `TextBox` has a name of **name1** etc.

[image]

Also here is an example output of the file:

[image]

**Improvements**

1. Filtering on the Textboxes - you may only want to do this for some textboxes for a particular name.
2. Loading the file. I have added the textbox name to the file, so theorically you could load the data back into the textboxes.